# How to run a ROS service client within a Gazebo plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo, call-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble getting a **service client** to work *within a Gazebo plugin*. It is a custom service called WaterCurrentLookup.

```
geometry_msgs/Point coordinate
---
geometry_msgs/Vector3 current
```

Inside the **Update method**/function of the gazebo plugin, the following code is used:

```
// fluid velocity / Water current service
ros::ServiceClient current_lookup_client_= rosnode_->serviceClient<freefloating_gazebo::WaterCurrentLookup>("water_current_client");

// std::cout << current_lookup_client_.exists(); -> This outputs 0       

freefloating_gazebo::WaterCurrentLookup srv;
srv.request.coordinate.x = 1;
srv.request.coordinate.y = 2;
srv.request.coordinate.z = 3;
        
bool success = current_lookup_client_.call(srv);
        
if (!success)
{
      ROS_ERROR_STREAM_THROTTLE(1, "Failed to retrieve fluid velocity");
}
else
{
      fluid_velocity_.Set(srv.response.current.x, srv.response.current.y, srv.response.current.z);
}
```

The server works, which is proven by running the following command:

```
rosservice call /get_water_current [1,1,1]
current: 
  x: 3.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
```

The header file is included (`#include <freefloating_gazebo/WaterCurrentLookup.h>`).

Somehow this does not work. The variable `success` is always **false**. When I check if current_lookup_client_ exists it outputs 0.
I've followed the tutorials and used the documentation, and cannot find out what I'm missing here. I'm using ROS Indigo.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

---

**SOLVED (Thanks to MIG):**

I didn't add the / to the service name:

```
ros::ServiceClient current_lookup_client_= rosnode_->serviceClient<freefloating_gazebo::WaterCurrentLookup>("/water_current_client");
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215759/how-to-run-a-ros-service-client-within-a-gazebo-plugin/) by [Eivind Froystad](https://answers.ros.org/users/23553/eivind-froystad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can see two possible problems here. I'm not sure what you actually ask, as the question is not completely precise...

1. You don't connect to the correct server (or any server at all):

When you set up the client, you connect to the service call `<node_namespace>/water_current_client`.
The test you provide, you call the service `/get_water_current`.
If this is the problem, change the Service client to `/get_water_current` and you should be okay.
Maybe also think of checking for the server existence with the `exists()` or `waitForService()`functions (see the [API docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1ServiceClient.html)).

2. The call to `current_lookup_client_.call()` returns false:

This seems to be a problem in your **Service Server**, not in the client.

Check if you have a `return false` in the Service Server callback somewhere. The `call()` function basically returns what you return from the Service Server Callback (which should return a bool), except if there is any communication error (in which case it also returns 'false' ).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eivind Froystad](https://answers.ros.org/users/23553/eivind-froystad/) on 2015-08-14**:
Thank you: The error was that I didn't add the / before the service name.